# Is it correct to omit preposition before date?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, prepositions, dates

Today, I received a mail from Steam and noticed that there was no preposition before the date. This is the part of the mail:

> SPECIAL PROMOTION! Offer ends 26 Apr 2:00am KST

Shouldn't it be:

> SPECIAL PROMOTION! Offer ends on 26 Apr at 2:00am KST

If it's okay to omit the prepositions before a date, are these sentences grammatically correct:

> The gift will arrive 26 Apr 2:00am KST.
>   He sent the message 26 Apr 2:00am KST.
>   It happens every Monday 2:00am KST.

Comment: Do a search for "headlinese".

Comment: ... Yes; 'on' has gone the same way as 'This is a', 'This' and 'at' here. Not to mention 'the' and 'a' in your title.  And being a Brit, I'd have to look KST up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'on' before the date (and the 'at' before the time) was dropped for effect -- this is a 'telegraphic style' that has become accepted in modern English in certain contexts through repeated use in the mass media. However it is not recommended for formal use in settings where absolutely correct grammar is called for.

Answer (score -2):

I would say it is American style also used in TV news programmes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/296388)

Comment: @jimm101 It looks like an answer, to me. If it's "American style", then it's considered correct in American English. And it clearly is considered correct in American English. Just look at any report in a reputable newspaper and it will say something like "Prime Minister Teresa May struggled Monday to keep her government from imploding" ([_Washington Post_](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/europe/theresa-mays-government-in-disarray-after-shock-resignation-by-brexit-minister/2018/07/09/b86533da-8357-11e8-8f6c-46cb43e3f306_story.html?utm_term=.ecd4b2eb89a1)); in British English, that would...

Comment: ... be "... struggled on Monday to..."